# Can you tell me what this frame is and year please

Tags: frames

[image]

I need to identify a bmx frame i have
Its a twin top rail[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you tell what brand/make/model of bike I have?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35823/how-do-you-tell-what-brand-make-model-of-bike-i-have)

Comment: See the answer from David Richerby in the question above

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments Richard already knows the frame is an Ammaco freestyle frame.
His real question is - Pro Ace or Koolstyler.

Here is a picture of a [1984 Koolstyler](http://www.23mag.com/mags/bmxbiker/bmxbiker.htm)
[image]

Here is a 1984 [Freestyle Pro King](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/ammaco/53224) (according to the person who posted the picture)
[image]

Focusing on the gusset your frame would have to be the Koolstyler. The pro has a cut out symbol and the Koolstyler does not.

[Mongoose Ammaco catalogue](http://www.vintagemongoose.com/pdfs/ammaco_winners.pdf)
[1984 Mongoose Ammaco price list](http://vintagemongoose.com/pdfs/mongoose_UKpricelist84.pdf)
Based on the price list they sold a Koolstyler, Freestyle Pro, Ace, and King.

By the way - in the original post it would have been very helpful to include what you already know. Also, your pictures focused on stamped numbers and logos - the numbers are not useful. Logos and frame construction are sometimes useful.

Comment: Yes the gusset is deffo the same as koolstyler, but i had a koolstyler new and it had the flat sided no bottom gusset as the kingunless this was a mod on later models to try to stop the crack? Didnt work if it was haha

Answer (score 0):

Some googling suggests its one or more of:

- **Akisu** because the majority of their frames were stamped DSBM made in Taiwan.  They made frames for Norco, redline,
- **Dodsun Bicycle and Machine Manufacturing** of Taiwan.  Again a frame supplier.
- **DS Bicycle Manufacturing**
- **Data and Safety Monitoring Board** ie a safety test, which would explain why its on many different brands.
- Or DSBM stands for "Design Specifics By Manufacturer" which is a kind of shorthand way of the manufacturer saying its a general frame that could have been used by a number of purchasers.

Point of all this, is that noone really knows why so many bikes are stamped with DSBM other than they all come from Asia.   There's really nothing to be gained from knowing your bike's parentage, other than a sense of completeness.

We can tell its a low-end bike because there's a clearly visible one-piece crank.  Its moderately interesting being a twin top tube, and the chrome appears to be in decent condition.

You should absolutely build it into a safe and rideable bike, and ride it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...what about the logo in the gusset and in the top rail? Yes i plan to refurb it and powder oat it but its how to remove the old chrome which is a problem to get removed

Comment: The logo is an Ammaco freestyler logo but how do i tell if its a pro ace or koolstyler

Comment: @Richard "how to remove old chrome" is a great separate question cos it has nothing to do with identifying this frame.