# What is my bike frame

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image].    What are those numbers on my bike frame?

Comment: Are you asking us to read them?  I get 65611215

Comment: see the answers to [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35823/how-do-you-tell-what-brand-make-model-of-bike-i-have)

Answer (score 1):

The numbers that are often punched into steel and aluminium frames below the bottom bracket are a serial or identifying number. You may have a look at Wikipedia for an explanation what a [serial number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_number) is.

If you know the make and model of your bike the number may help to identify your bike after it was stolen and recovered. For example: *"This 1996 Giant TCR is my bike and not just any of thousands of Giant TCRs because it has the very frame number I provided to police when reporting the theft."* It is therefore prudent to note the number.

With the exception of rare hand-built frames it has no other use.