# Any chance of identifying this tandem. (S/N T9012 737) Could be other numbers under cable guide. Manufactured around 1990 I think

Tags: identify-this-bike, tandems

Need to identify this tandem likely manufactured around 1990.  S/N T9012 737.  Could be additional numbers under the cable guide.

[image: picture 6 rotated 180]
[image: 1]
[[image: picture 2 rotated[2]]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 7]

Comment: The serial numbers are [basically zero use](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/35823/13174). If you want an ID, we'll need clear photos of the whole bike and close-ups of any distinctive parts. Voting to close as unclear for now, but will happily vote to reopen if you edit in some photos. Thanks!

Comment: Struggling to figure out how to upload photos.  Also what specific close-ups would be most helpful?

Comment: If you upload them to somewhere like Imgur and post a link in the comments, somebody will edit them into the question for you. Any part of the bike that looks like it's a distinctive or unusual shape could be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Please follow [How do I ask a good “ID My Bike” question?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question) to improve the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @BobRains thank you - I've in-lined your images.  They're not very big but a picture is literally worth a thousand words.   Can you add more info on the tags around the front stem?  They appear to have words on them.  There's a blue sticker on the stem too - whats it say?  Finally the head tube area on front - please look there for a badge, logo, name, or anything.

Comment: Also - can be worth checking what the frame is made of.  I'm 95% sure it will be steel (highly attractive to a magnet) but there's a small chance its aluminium (completely inert to a magnet) or maybe titanium (vaguely responsive to a magnet, nothing like steel though)   So please do the magnet test and see what kind of attraction there is.

Comment: And the read dropouts can be another place worth looking for names and brands.  May have to drop the wheel or clean around to see something.

Comment: I will note that the frame layout is very unusual.  In particular, the diagonal running from the back seat to to the front bottom bracket is hardly ever seen (though you see a diagonal in the opposite direction quite a bit).  But the welds are almost certainly done in a factory, so it's unlikely to be home-brew.

Comment: Some of the tubes have been wrapped with reflective/sparkle tape/paper/something. The seam on the wrap can be seen in the last picture - underside of the bottom bracket. Looks like the original color was black with splatters. I wonder if there are any decals under the sparkle paper. If Bob is open to a little pealing the head tube might be a good place to look. Pealing off the sparkle might damage any decal - so it's risky.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this thread](https://www.bikeforums.net/tandem-cycling/985974-another-gary-fisher-gemini.html) Bob is correct. His bike is a Gary Fisher Gemini. The tandem in the thread is a good match for Bob's bike.

[image]

From the thread

> I ran into a former Fisher employee at NAHBS this last weekend and was asking him about the tandem. All he could tell me was that the early ones were made in Mexico and weren't very well made. I suspect that yours and mine are later, Asian made bikes as mine, at least, seems reasonably well made. I'm still trying to figure out who designed it and decided to use the "uptube". I suspect that was the cheapest, easiest way to build it. Ritchey still uses the uptube design in their tandem, though Santana insists it makes no sense. At least it gives you a place to put a water bottle. The placement of the stoker seat tube cage won't allow the use of larger modern bottles. We use a clamp-on handlebar mount for the second stoker bottle. -- fxsvelo

later

> Serial number on mine is 19012-0707. It has (mostly) Shimano DX components; the catalog scans I've been able to find show Suntour XC on the 91-93 models. So maybe mine's an '89. Guess it doesn't matter too much!  -- rcschafer

I suspect he's wrong about the serial number based on the picture in the original question - it's probably T9012-0707

According to the [Fisher catalogs](http://www.vintage-trek.com/trek-fisher-klein-lemond.htm) for 1989 and 1990 the Gemini had a Shimano Deore II drivetrain. The Gemini was first sold in 1989, the last year was 1993. Fisher started using a Suntour derailleurs and a Sugino crankset in 1991.
Seems like Bob has a 1989 or 1990 model.

Comment: Great spotting!  Well done.

Answer (score 2):

That is one gorgeous touring tandem.  While I don't have a brand, here are some observations.

It is particularly long in the back half of the frame, giving the stoker a lot more room.  A racing tandem is much shorter, whereas this gives more view, or more space to hang frame bags.

The big chainring is an enormous dinner plate of 58 to 60 tooth, and the grannie is fairly normal sized at 36 tooth.  So this is not a beginner's bike, this bike is meant to go long distances at a high but comfortable pace.

Not sure what cassette is on it, but I'm guessing a MTB style based on the cranks being branded Deore.  So perhaps 12-32 tooth.  So this bike can go up most hills okay but excells in the flat-lands.

Butterfly bars also suggest a long-haul commuter, with many hand positions for the captain.  The stoker can sit up and go hands-free much easier.

I only see two brakes - the front is definitely a V brake while the rear could be either V brake or cantilever.  I do NOT see a drum as a third brake which is common on tandems for hills.  Again this suggests being targetted for flat land use.

Comment: The tags around the front stem are from several RAGBRAI rides (across the state of Iowa) with the oldest from 1993.  I was told recently that it may be a Gary Fisher Gemini first made in 1989.