# How can I identify my bikes make through the serial number?

Tags: frames

[image]  I can't identify my bike so I was hoping someone could help me... The serial number is AX365316

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: That looks like an old school race BMX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what year my bike was made?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47078/how-can-i-tell-what-year-my-bike-was-made)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you tell what brand/make/model of bike I have?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35823/how-do-you-tell-what-brand-make-model-of-bike-i-have)

Comment: Regarding serial numbers: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/62264/13174),

> The serial number on its own is basically useless. They're not like VINs on cars: there's no global database of them and they're not even guaranteed to be unique. Each manufacturer of frames uses whatever scheme they want, and the serial numbers are purely for their own stock control.
>
> To identify the frame, you need to compare its appearance to frames whose manufacturer you know. However, unless there's something very distinctive about your particular frame, it's unlikely that anyone will manage to identify it. Most frames have nothing particularly special about them, and many are made in enormous factories in China that sell frames to whatever brand wants to buy.
>
> If you've identified a small number of possible manufacturers, the format of the serial number might allow you to tell which of them is correct. But even then, it's something of a long shot.
>
> See also, [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/52060/13174)