# What is this bike called

Tags: road-bike

SIm trying to find the name of my bike NFSD140S1561 is the serial number. its a bmx style and says pacific on the frame. Can anyone give me any info?

Comment: Please have a look at these answers https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/63332/how-can-i-identify-my-bikes-make-through-the-serial-number as well as
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35823/how-do-you-tell-what-brand-make-model-of-bike-i-have

Answer (score 1):

Serial numbers are not standard, each manufacturer has its own coding.
It looks your BMX is a Schwinn BMX produced by

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Cycle

Mass product coming form the East, built to entice people looking for an object that looks like a bicycle and works almost like a bicycle, but generally with low-tier components and manufacturing not always having higher standards and QC.

Final opinion: if you like it and you like the way it rides, then it is a great bike.